# assigning variable to integer value retrieve from mysql table

Tags: python

I have used multiprocessing to write code for sensing data from three sensors. Actually I have retrive data from mysql table and assigned it to the variable. It is worked for first two sensors but for the third sensor it gives error. The small part of code is as follows,

```
def humidity_sensor():
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'root',passwd=       'mumbai',db = 'Sensordata')

 cursor = conn.cursor()
 cursor.execute("SELECT `DVCPORTmc1_ID`, `DVCPORTmc1_DVCm_ID`,
 `DVCPORTmc1_Port_No`, `DVCPORTmc1_SENSRm_ID`, `DVCPORTmc1_Start_Dt`,\
 `DVCPORTmc1_Start_Time`, `DVCPORTmc1_End_Dt`, `DVCPORTmc1_End_Time`,
 `DVCPORTmc1_Read_Interval`,`DVCPORTmc1_Added_by`)      
  FROM `M_Device_Port` WHERE DVCPORTmc1_data_del='0' and
  DVCPORTmc1_Is_Active='0' and DVCPORTmc1_DVCm_ID = '16' and
  DVCPORTmc1_Description='humidity sensor'")

            row=cursor.fetchone()
            interval3=int(row[8])
  while True:
       try:
          date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
          clock = time.strftime("%H:%M")
          temp,humidity,light = main.reading()
          cursor.execute("INSERT INTO sensor(date, clock, port,value)
          VALUES(%s, %s, %s,%s)",(date, clock,2,humidity))
          conn.commit()
          time.sleep(interval3)
       except:
           conn.rollback()

  p1=Process(target=light_sensor)
  p2=Process(target=temp_sensor)
  p3=Process(target=humidity_sensor)
  p1.start()
  p2.start()
  p3.start()
```

which gives error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 interval3=int(row[8])
Typeerror: 'NoneType'object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Maybe row=cursor.fetchone() returns None.

Comment: @Valijon: Not maybe, I think it's sure that it returns None.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
interval3=int(row[8])
```

[x] is the getitem method. But as I see here, row is None.
That's why you can't acces the element at index 8, because row is None
and you can't call getitem on None.

This means cursor.fetchone() returns None.

Comment: Just to add: check your query condition `DVCPORTmc1_Description='humidity sensor'` if it returns value

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with query to retrieve data from mysql table.It gives the output none i.e. when using  cursor.fetchone () it gives NONE. So the integer value which is assigned for interval3 is NONE.